# Problem mapping API-derived values into a React.js state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm brand new to working with React/Axios.

I'm trying to store the data from the urban dictionary API via Axios into the definitions empty array in the state.

I'm then trying to render the name of each definition to the browser via  the render function.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      definitions: [],
      errors: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUrbDef();
  }

  getUrbDef() {
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com/define',
      headers: {'host': 'mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com', 'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'keydata'},
      params: {'term': 'world'}
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .then(response =>
      response.data.list.map(definition => ({
        name: `${definition.definition}`,
        id: `${definition.defid}`,
      }))
    )
    .then(definitions => {
      console.log(definitions);
      this.setState({
        definitions,
        isLoading: false
      });
      })
    .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
  }

  // Renders to the browser
  render() {
    // Grabbing objects to use from state
    let definitions = this.state.definitions;
```

As previously mentioned, this is my first time using React.js in this way, so I'm a little bit stumped - any help would be greatly appreciated!

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-neumann-28rhe

Comment: try replace `console.log(response)` with `response.json()`. You need to turn Response stream into something you can process like JSON

Comment: It's because you weren't returning anything where you had the `console.log(response)` so the next then didn't have any input so simply removing that `.then()` block fixes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `then` handler isn't returning anything:

```
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
})
```

**Explanation**:

Calling `then` returns a Promise that gets resolved/rejected depending on what's happening inside the handler function.

In your case, the handler isn't returning anything (`console.log(response)`), so the promise returned by `then` gets resolved with an undefined value, as a result:

```
.then(response =>
  response.data.list.map(definition => ({
    name: `${definition.definition}`,
    id: `${definition.defid}`,
  }))
)
```

receives undefined.

What you can do to fix this is to either:

1) return `response` inside `then` handler:

```
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
  return response;
})
```

2) remove the first `then` from the chain:

```
axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'https://mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com/define',
  headers: {'host': 'mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com', 'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'keydata'},
  params: {'term': 'world'}
})
.then(response =>
  response.data.list.map(definition => ({
    name: `${definition.definition}`,
    id: `${definition.defid}`,
  }))
)
```

[then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Answer (score 0):

El Aoutar Hamza is right. But I'd like to change a little.

```js
axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'https://mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com/define',
  headers: {'host': 'mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com', 'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'keydata'},
  params: {'term': 'world'}
}).then(response => {
  console.log(response);
  return response.data;
}).then(data => data.list.map(definition => ({
  name: `${definition.definition}`,
  id: `${definition.defid}`,
}))).then(definitions => {
  console.log(definitions);
  this.setState({
    definitions,
    isLoading: false
  });
}).catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
```